# "WooCommerceAPI' has already been declared

Tags: reactjs, react-native

```
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-woocommerce-api
```

```
import WooCommerceAPI from 'react-native-woocommerce-api';
```

```
const WooCommerceAPI = new WooCommerceAPI({
  url: 'https://yourstore.com', // Your store URL
  ssl: true,
  consumerKey: 'ck_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', // Your consumer secret
  consumerSecret: 'cs_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', // Your consumer secret
  wpAPI: true, // Enable the WP REST API integration
  version: 'wc/v3', // WooCommerce WP REST API version
  queryStringAuth: true,
});
```

Error: TransformError SyntaxError: Identifier 'WooCommerceAPI' has already been declared.

Answer (score 0):

It might be because of same variable name try changing your initialized `WooCommerceAPI` variable name like this:

```
const WooCommerce = new WooCommerceAPI({
  url: 'https://yourstore.com', // Your store URL
  ssl: true,
  consumerKey: 'ck_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', // Your consumer secret
  consumerSecret: 'cs_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', // Your consumer secret
  wpAPI: true, // Enable the WP REST API integration
  version: 'wc/v3', // WooCommerce WP REST API version
  queryStringAuth: true,
});
```